# Permission denied to access public ssh key

Tags: 18.04, ssh, ssh-agent

I can't add my ssh public key to the ssh-agent and my ssh folder is odd I believe.[here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2bIu.png)

Comment: What is the output from `ls -lad /home/maydara/.ssh /home/maydata` and `id`

Comment: @mdpc drwxr-xr-x 38 maydara maydara 4096 Dec  5 02:20 /home/maydara
drw-------  2 maydara maydara 4096 Dec  5 00:54 /home/maydara/.ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix my problem I ended up removing my ssh folder and regenarating my keys:

```
rm -rf ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
ssh-add ~/.ssh/[the_name_of_your_private_key]
```

then I uploaded my public keys again to github, digitalocean, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The fix is `chmod 700 /home/maydara/.ssh`

Without the 'x' permission, a directory cannot be searched (i.e. files in directory cannot be found).

Edit: Also it might be necessary to change the owner of the .ssh directory and authorized_key file if they've been originally created with root.

```
chown -R maydara:maydara /home/maydara/.ssh
```

Comment: @Mbpc i've tried this before i wrote this post and it didn't work, I ended up deleting the whole folder and the keys then I started from scratch.

Comment: @Getsuga You might like to add that as an answer. :-)

Comment: @Kulfy thx for the suggestion but what i've done is not really a fix, it's a rebuild from scratch and that won't be helpful for people who don't have copies of their ssh keys.

Comment: @Getsuga Answer section is meant for posting things which solved the problem. I've seen many a times people do post a re-installation as their answer (since they solved their problem by re-installation). Your solution might help those who have **copies**. So, please write that as an answer and mark that answer as accepted. :-)

Comment: @Getsuga perhaps you created the user's .ssh directory with root user. If so, you also need to change the owner of the directory and its contents (presumably authorized_keys file) chown -R maydara:maydara /home/maydara/.ssh